# Is it possible to use jboss for session replication with Non EJB objects like spring bean

Tags: spring, jboss, ejb, session-replication

We have an enterprise web application . The UI is built on the top of flex ,  middle tier is defined with spring bean and at DAO layer we are using ibatis . **Is it possible to use jboss to replicate sessions within cluster nodes for this web application ?**

I went through the Jboss documentation and they were just saying that EJBs can be session replicated using jboss , they have no documentation for non ejb objects

I configured Jboss with session replication with my web application and I see following logs all over places in the serve logs .

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.marshallCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:281)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.processSingleCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:300)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:179)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.NotActiveException: Fields were never written
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.finish(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:175)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1009)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:885)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:680)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:62)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:119)
```

Comment: Which version of JBoss do you have ? Are you using JSF ? There's an similar issue : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=957838

Comment: We are on Jboss 6.1 EAP and we are not using JSF .